# django REST urls.py does not resolve endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

Noob here. I am using https://github.com/Seedstars/django-react-redux-base which is great and straight forward Django REST + React.js starter project. This is Django 1.11.

My problem is with the Django REST backend not resolving the API endpoints correctly. I have added an application `profiles`  that should return a user profile when queried by:

```
/api/v1/profiles/getprofile/(some_name)
```

Here is my top-level `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

from base import views as base_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^api/v1/getdata/', include('base.urls', namespace='base')),
    url(r'^api/v1/profiles/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles')),
    url(r'', cache_page(settings.PAGE_CACHE_SECONDS)(base_views.IndexView.as_view()), name='index'),
]
```

My `profiles/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(_(r'^getprofile/(?P<display_name>.*)/$'),
        views.PublicProfileView.as_view(),
        name='getprofile'),
]
```

With This setup, when I query http://localhost:8000/api/v1/profiles/getprofile/test, I get the IndexView in the response, basically html containing the frontend. However if I comment out *r''* from the top level urls.py I get the expected JSON payload for the 'test' profile that I have in the database. Why would the resolver skip *r'^api/v1/profiles/* and resolve straight to *r''*? Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, and mark it as accepted, so people browsing can see this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, it was a matter of clearing stale pyc files and most importantly setting the correct headers in the API request:

To clear the *.pyc files:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm '{}' ';'
```

Correct headers to request JASON response:

```
headers : {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these following:

```
app_name = getprofile

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^getprofile/(?P<display_name>.*)/$',views.PublicProfileView.as_view(),name='getprofile'),
]
```

If it does not work, please give us the error message, like "template does not exist" ,for example.

Comment: This fails with:
  File "/home/vpe/src/golrn/masterlrn/src/profiles/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    app_name = getprofile
NameError: name 'getprofile' is not defined